# problema con ruta y comando

Tags: html, css, laravel

Tengo un problema con la rutas y comandos  de mis códigos, pasa que no logro crear la ruta "/crear" porque al ingresar al servidor me redirige a otra pagina.

Y estuve viendo que en el controlador  show(cumple la función de mostrar) tengo que cambiar "lista" para que me muestre los datos ingresados y si quiere ingresar datos tengo que borrar "lista" y cambiarlo por "index" que es la vista para crear pero yo quiero crear una pagina para crear y otra para mostrar los datos que he ingresado.

Dejo mi código:

```
public function show(){

        $cars=Car::all();

        return view ('lista',['cars'=>$cars]);

 /*
 En este sector al cambiar "lista me muestra la pagina para 
 ingresar datos pero sigue estando en la ruta /lista y 
 yo quiero que pase eso en la ruta /crear.**
 */

public function crear(ClearRequest $request){

        if($request->isMethod('get')){ 
        return view('index'); }

        $patente=$request['patente'];

        $marca=$request['marca'];

        $modelo=$request['modelo'];

        $color=$request['color'];

        $fecha_ingreso=$request['fecha_ingreso'];

        $car=new Car();

        $car->patente=$patente;

        $car->marca=$marca;

        $car->modelo=$modelo;

        $car->color=$color;

        $car->fecha_ingreso=$fecha_ingreso;

        $car->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    }
```

los controladores:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/crear',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@crear',

    'as'=>'cars.crear' ]);

Route::get('/lista',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@show',

    'as'=>'carsd.show'
]   
);
```

Comment: Tienes en la action de crear esto `return redirect()->back();`, basicamente eso hace una redirección

Comment: Puedes intentar preguntar dentro del action de crear if($request->isMethod('get')){ return view('tuvista'); } y despues dejas el codigo que tenias anteriormente asi si es un get el metodo direccionas para la vista de crear sino hace la operación de crear

Comment: integro el if en el metodo crear del controlador y sigue redireccionando a otra pagina y no a la ruta /crear que tengo definido para ello

Comment: pon en tu pregunta lo que cambiastes y a que ruta esta redireccionando

Comment: edite el codgio arriba, podrías ver si es como usted esta diciendo por favor, muchas gracias

Comment: Como estas accediendo a esa url por la barra del navegador o a traves de un formulario u otro link de tu mismo sistema???

Comment: acceso a traves de la barra del navegador y tambien tengo un boton que dirige para ingresar datos pero se redirecciona a la principal no cambia